# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

Tags: android, crash, andengine, crash-reports

Some users are getting this crash too frequently in my app developed in andengine. 
I am not detaching/attaching any objects but still I am getting this error. I am using object visibility and unregistertoucharea though which I didn't put into runonupdate. Can that cause this issue. If not can someone please tell me what might?

This is the crash report I am getting from Google Play.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at org.andengine.c.a.d(Unknown Source)
at org.andengine.c.c.e.d(Unknown Source)
at org.andengine.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
at org.andengine.b.a.b(Unknown Source)
at org.andengine.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
at org.andengine.opengl.e.g.onDrawFrame(Unknown Source)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Sometime the game is crashing on gameover and sometime is crashing on restarting the game

When the game is over I am calling the following function

```
public void GameOver(){
    yourScoreText.setText(""+score);        
    restart_button.setVisible(true);
    leaderboard_button.setVisible(true);
    share_button.setVisible(true);
    gameOverText.setVisible(true);
    gameOverOverlay.setVisible(true);
    yourScoreText.setVisible(true);
    highScoreText.setVisible(true);

    this.registerTouchArea(restart_button);
    this.registerTouchArea(leaderboard_button);
    this.registerTouchArea(share_button);
}
```

When the restart is pressed I am calling the following function.

```
public void RestartGame(){
    restart_button.setVisible(false);
    leaderboard_button.setVisible(false);
    share_button.setVisible(false);
    gameOverText.setVisible(false);
    gameOverOverlay.setVisible(false);
    yourScoreText.setVisible(false);
    highScoreText.setVisible(false);
    this.unregisterTouchArea(restart_button);
    this.unregisterTouchArea(leaderboard_button);
    this.unregisterTouchArea(share_button);
    score = 0;
    scoreText.setText("Score: "+score);

    Log.d("game start","game has been started");
    StartScreen();
}
public void StartScreen(){
    leaderboard_home_button.setVisible(true);
    rate_button.setVisible(true);
    if(activity.getNoAds()==0){
        no_ads_button.setVisible(true);
        this.registerTouchArea(no_ads_button);
    }
    if(isMute){
        sound_off_button.setVisible(true);
        this.registerTouchArea(sound_off_button);
    } else {
        sound_on_button.setVisible(true);
        this.registerTouchArea(sound_on_button);
    }
    this.registerTouchArea(leaderboard_home_button);
    this.registerTouchArea(rate_button);

}
```

Comment: what line in your code gives you this exception ? can you tell?

Comment: I'm almost sure it is the .setText method, is it?

Comment: How you initialize your text objects?

Comment: No idea what line is causing the exception. Here is how I am defining text objects.
@ranifisch
private Text highScoreText;
then in createscene function 
highScoreText = new Text(SOME_X, SOME_Y, resourceManager.font, "New Best: 1234", new TextOptions(HorizontalAlign.CENTER), vbom);

Comment: And what is the score when it crashes?

Comment: @ranifisch 1/2/3  digits

Comment: Can't help , only if you will say which line makes this exception, debug it and you will find out.

Comment: @ranifisch That's what I am not able to figure out actually. Or this might be an andengine issue too.

Comment: use Log.d and debug code line by line until it crashes... it must crash somewhere.

Comment: @ranifisch The issue is it is not crashing on every device. In fact it never crashed on my device. As I said very few users are facing this crash and that too not always.

Answer (score 3):

Array indexes are count from 0. 
So if Array's size = 2, it has these indexes : 0, 1. So in this case, index number 2 do not exists.

*PS : if you want more details, provide us some code and I will edit my answer ;)*

Comment: Updated the question. It is not a issue of me defining/using array. This is something happening from andengine/android's side. The crash happens only sometimes but this is the max number of crash I am getting from users.

Comment: I actually do not know andengine, but what I know is the meaning of the thrown Exception. I can ensure you that your problem is an index that is not in your array (the name of the Exception tells you this). If it's not your code, either you don't give the right information to your framework somewhere (like declaring the array size ?) or the framework has a bug and you can tell it to developers ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem relies on initializing your Text object.
When you initialize it, you need to set the max length of it:

```
private Text highScoreText = new Text(SOME_X, SOME_Y, resourceManager.font, "New Best: 1234567890", new TextOptions(HorizontalAlign.CENTER), vbom);
```

Dont forget to do the same for the Score text object.

Comment: But score is never going into more than 3 digits. So I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: Check the initialization of the other Text objects too.